# Antialiasing an entire scene after resterization

Tags: opengl, glut, antialiasing

I ran into an issue while compiling an openGl code. The thing is that i want to achieve full scene anti-aliasing and i don't know how. I turned on force-antialiasing from the Nvidia control-panel and that was what i really meant to gain. I do it now with GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH. Obviously it is not efficient and good-looking. Here are the questions

1) Should i use multi sampling? 
2) Where in the pipeline does openGl blend the colors for antialiasing?
3) What alternatives do exist besides GL_*_SMOOTH and multisampling?

Comment: Isn't AA a part of rasterisation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH is *not* a method to do Full-screen AA (FSAA).

Not sure what you mean by "not efficient" in this context, but it certainly is not good looking, because of its tendency to blend in the middle of meshes (at the triangle edges).

Now, with respect to FSAA and your questions:

1. Multisampling (aka MSAA) is the standard way today to do FSAA. The usual alternative is super-sampling (SSAA), that consists in rendering at a higher resolution, and downsample at the end. It's much more expensive.
2. The specification says that logically, the GL keeps a sample buffer (4x the size of the pixel buffer, for 4xMSAA), and a pixel buffer (for a total of 5x the memory), and on each sample write to the sample buffer, updates the pixel buffer with the *resolved* value from the current 4 samples in the sample buffer (It's not called blending, by the way. Blending is what happens at the time of the write into the sample buffer, controlled by `glBlendFunc` et al.). In practice, this is not what happens in hardware though. Typically, you write only to the sample buffer (and the hardware usually tries to compress the data), and when comes the time to use it, the GL implementation will resolve the full buffer at once, before the usage happens. This also helps if you actually use the sample buffer directly (no need to resolve at all, then).
3. I covered SSAA and its cost. The latest technique is called Morphological anti-aliasing (MLAA), and is actively being researched. The idea is to do a post-processing pass on the fully rendered image, and anti-alias what looks like sharp edges. Bottom line is, it's not implemented by the GL itself, you have to code it as a post-processing pass. I include it for reference, but it can cost [quite a lot](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/more-on-god-of-war-iii-antialiasing/).

Comment: MLAA is really awesome, but don't try this unless you really have a LOT of time to implement it correctly. You should go for MSAA.

Comment: @Calvin1602: Indeed. That's why I mentioned it as "still being researched" :D

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a post about this here: [Getting smooth, big points in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513811/getting-smooth-big-points-in-opengl/1513979#1513979)

You have to specify WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS and WGL_SAMPLES (or GLX prefix for XOrg/GLX) before creating your OpenGL context, when selecting a pixel format or visual.

On Windows, make sure that you use `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()` if you want a pixel format with extended traits, NOT `ChoosePixelFormat()` from GDI/GDI+. wglChoosePixelFormatARB has to be queried with wglGetProcAddress from the ICD driver, so you need to create a dummy OpenGL context beforehand. WGL function pointers are valid even after the OpenGL context is destroyed.

WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS is a boolean (1 or 0) that toggles multisampling. WGL_SAMPLES is the number of buffers you want. Typically 2,4 or 8.