# glXChooseFBConfig() setting for anti-aliasing?

Tags: opengl, multisampling, glx

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513811/getting-smooth-big-points-in-opengl/1513979#1513979), it is stated that

> **To request a visual with multisampling with XLib**, use these two attributes in the list to glXChooseFBConfig():
>
> GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS - its value should be True. This is an on/off
>   toggle. 
>   GLX_SAMPLES - the number of samples.

These of which, according to the wiki on Multisampling section in opengl.org, glXChooseFBConfig() does accept these attributes. However, GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS/GLX_SAMPLES don't appeared to be specified in an SDK [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml). Do you might know why?

Comment: Because the 2.1 man pages are old, out-of-date, and *dangerously* erronous? Seriously, if you're going to use the "SDK" man pages, use the [4.x ones](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/).

Comment: There isn't glx section on SDK 4...? The latest on there seemed to be the legacy 2.1 unless there is a more 'up-to-date' section I can be pointed to?

Comment: Be aware, if Intel has its way in a couple of years on Linux, we'll all be using EGL instead of GLX :) Sounds good in theory, we'll see if it ever comes to fruition - especially since it's being spearheaded by Intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you download the GLX-1.4 specification PDF, which is the much better reference manual: http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glx1.4.pdf